# How to access the Internet only via BIOS?

Tags: tcp, operating-system, kernel, bios

I'm writing a mini OS just for fun. I want to save some key information to one securiry server on the Internet and ever fetch it BEFORE booting my OS.

So my problem is: **How to access the Internet only via BIOS?** i.e. **How to use the TCP protocol in BIOS environment?**

PS.

It is obvious that diskless workstations use such a technique. So it is technically possible.

Comment: @John_J No. I have gave up to dig deeper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Diskless workstations use [PXE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preboot_Execution_Environment) which is part of NIC (network card) ROM or a BIOS extension, it's a simple environment that implements TCP/IP stack that can get a executable over TFTP and run it.

There is an open source one that you could modify [iPXE](http://ipxe.org/) to your needs and replace your existing PXE ROM.

Comment: Thank you, Raber. ipxe.org is very useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is possible. You need to implement a network driver into the BIOS to achiving that. So I would say this is not possible. By the way I never read that someone wrote his/her own BIOS.

Comment: It is obvious that diskless workstations use such a technique. So it is technically possible.

Comment: Diskless workstations works normally with network boot this is post BIOS.

Comment: How to boot a diskless workstation from the view of ROM module developer? This is the same problem as mine. The necessity of writing an private OS is not related to the original problem. I just want to use TCP protocol under BIOS environment.

Comment: I don't know ROM module developing, but for network book you need to setup a DHCP server, a TFTP server and some more. I'm sure it will be simple for you to google for network boot. I installed a linux system over the network this was fun :-)

Answer (score -1):

If you have an ethernet port on your pc/router buy a Gil.Net router and connect it wirelessly to your home router and then plug in the router

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).